# post custom values

Tags: array

I have this code:

```
            <?php $site= get_post_custom_values('projLink'); 
                if($site[0] != ""){

            ?>
                <p><a href="<?=$site[0]?>">Visit the Site</a></p>

            <?php }else{ ?>
                <p><em>Live Link Unavailable</em></p>
            <?php } ?>
```

After clicking the link I get this adress in the browser http://domain.com/Array

So i don´t think the

```
    <?=$site[0]?>
```

is correct.

How can I make it work? Thanks

Comment: Sure you don't want to use the [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `var_dump($site[0])` to see the structure of the array. And once you know that, then you can properly reference an item in that array. (You could also do `var_dump($site)` to get a full picture of what's going on.)

Comment: sorry I don´t understand! you mean i replace     <?=$site[0]?>
    with that code?

Comment: `<?php var_dump($site); ?>` This won't solve your problem, but will give all info necessary to solve the problem. ie. Once I see the info outputted by var_dump, I know exactly how to work with an array.

Comment: Ok! Now my link looks like this: http://domain.com/array(1) {  [0]=>  string(17)

Comment: Based on the above, your code should work. Perhaps you should consider get_post_meta() as Geert suggested, since you are only interested in one value anyway, and there is only one value returned.